# Windows 10 multi-screen how to move to screen on all edge when not same size

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have following multi-screen configuration (screen 1 is a laptop, 2 and 3 are extra screen above the laptop's one):
[image]

But moving from top screens (2 and 3 then) to screen 1 can only be achieved from yellow part on screenshot above.

Anybody knows a way to be able to go to laptop also from left and right (where there are red crosses above), even if it is not matching a part of bottom screen and then they "teleport" to corresponding top corner of screen 1 ?

Edit: I know current behavior is the expected one and makes sense, it just seems better to me to be able to go down from anywhere.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: I believe what you want is only possible with third-party software, even then I have my doubts, what you want is even possible.  The behavior you describe is expected, the real solution to the problem, is use a resolution hat is the same width as the two individual monitors for the third monitor.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I edited my question with what you said about expected behavior, and I'll check for possible third-party software doing that.